# Create revision when a property of a list element is changed

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

Let's assume I have the following entities:

```
public class Group
{
    public IList<Item> Items { get; set; } 
}

public class Item
{
    public Group Group { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Now I want Envers to create a revision for `Group` when the `Name` property of `Item` has changed. The `revision_on_collection_change` property just works if I change the collection (as the name suggests ;-) itself.

Is there a possibilty to setup Envers to 'connect' the parent entity with properties of its child element properties?

Comment: triggers are your friend.

Comment: What for triggers, where to define them? I cannot find anything at the Envers documentation.

Comment: I'm sure he means database triggers - code you configure the database to execute which is triggered by various events.  For example, you could add a trigger that fires whenever Item changes are inserted into the audit table which then inserts the appropriate Group change as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: 
No.

Longer answer:
Depending on your use case there are alternatives that *might* suit your needs. Either make sure that your Group entity will be modified when one of its Items are or include revisions with modified Items when querying for a Group (the latter would probably need your relation to be bidirectional though).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The relation is already bidirectional. Could you give me an hint how to include revisions with modified items while querying?

Comment: Roger, I am still searching for a solution of this problem. Please could you help me?

Comment: As said, envers doesnt support this. But you can of course make sure that parent always be modifies each time a child is (either interceptor/event listeners or fix it in your domain model). Or, maybe, you can query the children to get the revisions where they have been changed and then make a query on parent using these revision numbers.